# How to save JSONdata into a set?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a data set. It is of the form
{
  "name1": 123
  "name2": 234
  "name3": 345
   .
   .
   .
}

Now, I am using a @RestController to read this through PostMan. I have a class test.java.
I have a function,

```
public void testController(@RequestBody String request)
```

I'm running this through a local host with the help of @RequestMapping. I need to save the above data set one by one in an object. The object is as follows.

```
public class OperatorClass implements Comparable<OperatorClass>{
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<>();

    OperatorClass(String name, String id)
    {
        add_id(id);
        add_name(name);
    }
```

I am trying to save this data in the following way, which by the way I have figured out is wrong.

```
try {
        JSONObject array = new JSONObject(request);
        Iterator<String> stringIterator1 = array.keys();
        stringIterator1.next();
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        OperatorClass oco = new OperatorClass(array.keys().,array.get(array.keys().toString()).toString());
        System.out.println(oco.get_Name());
        System.out.println(oco.get_Id());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I know it is wrong because array.keys() gives all the name1, name2, name3 data. What I want to know is how to get just name 1 for this. And how to get it's following ID, to insert into a particular object.I was trying to save the object into a set of operator class.

Comment: I am sorry I feel I have missed a part of this question. I was trying to save the object into a Set set<OperatorClass>

Comment: You can edit your question and add what is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have got an answer to this problem. We use

```
String temp = stringIterator1.next();
```

And instead of

```
OperatorClass oco = new OperatorClass(array.keys().,array.get(array.keys().toString()).toString());
```

We use,

```
OperatorClass oco = new OperatorClass(temp, array.get(temp).toString);
```

Just remember that using string iterator will probably not display the values in the order of the data set, due to hash mapping.